# `react-native-dropdown-picker` not selecting default value for multiSelect, if list item having selected:true {label:"A", value:1, selected:true}

Tags: react-native, react-native-dropdown-picker

I am trying to use multiselect feature of **react-native-dropdown-picker** which is working fine for selecting item, I can select multiple Items and can get its values too, but my problem is I am not able to show `defaultValue` on screen load.

I am fetching data from server and then trying to show on `dropdown-picker`

```
const AccountSelection = (props) => {
      const [accountId, setAccount] = useState([])
      const [accountList, setAccountList] = useState([])
      const [defaultAccount, setDefaultAccount] = useState([])

      useEffect(() => {
        getAccounts()      
      }, [])

      const getAccounts = () => {
        axiosConfig.get('/accounts')
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    const accountData = response.data.payload.data
                        const accountNames = accountData.map((item) => ({ label: item.name, value: item.id, selected: item.id == store.usersDefaultValues.account_id ? true : false }))
                        setAccountList(accountNames)
                        setDefaultAccount(accountNames.find(item => item.selected == true ? item.value : null))
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("axios error", error);
            })
       }

       return (
                <View>
                    <DropDownPicker
                        placeholder="Select Account"
                        value={accountId}
                        items={accountList}
                        onChangeItem={(val) => setAccountId(val)}
                        defaultValue={defaultAccount}
                        multiple={true}
                        activeItemStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#F5CCF8' }}
                    ></DropDownPicker>
                </View>
        )
 }
```

On screen Load I am getting blank dropdown-picker, where it should show `1 Item Selected`.

[image]

In DropDownPickerProps in **react-native-dropdown-picker** optional `selected` key is available but it is not working

```
items: {
      label: any;
      value: any;
      icon?: () => JSX.Element;
      hidden?: boolean;
      disabled?: boolean;
      selected?: boolean;
    }[];
```

Please share if anyone have solution for this. Thank you.

Comment: On your defaultValue, you is getting from defaultAccount that is an array. This prop defaultValue accepts an array, or should you put just one item to display? Choosing by index, or something like this. defaultValue={defaultAccount[0]} ?

Comment: Hi @DefyingL, I am using multiple select, in some cases I could have multiple default ids to be select on screen load.

Comment: same situation with me .. any one got any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The `defaultValue` attribute is not longer supported in `react-native-dropdown-picker`. If you want to select a default value, you simply need to set the 'value' variable to the default value's `value`.

You can read more in this issue: https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker/issues/511#issuecomment-1049110163.